# I am unable to access the object within the struct

Tags: c, struct

I am having trouble inserting the file value string "Elizabeth" into the first name[21].  I know it works if with a stand alone variable within the function but am not quite sure how to make it work with structs.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
struct student_record
{
int student_id;
int student_age;
char first_name[21];
char last_name[22];
};

struct student_record_node
{
 struct student_record *record;
 struct student_record_node *next;
};

void parseFile(char *filename,struct student_record_node**head);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
struct student_record_node *head;
parseFile(argv[1], &head);

return 0;
}
void parseFile(char *filename, struct student_record_node**head)
{
        FILE *fp;

        fp = fopen(filename, "r"); //creates a POINTER to "filename"
        struct student_record_node *new_student;
        new_student = malloc(sizeof(struct student_record_node));

        if(new_student == NULL)
        {printf("failed"); }
        fscanf(fp, "%s", new_student->record->first_name); /*problem here*/``

}
```

Comment: Think about where `new_student->record` points to.  What have you assigned it to be?

Comment: You are missing space allocation for `new_student->record` . before fscanf do a malloc for new_student->record. Things will work.. cheers..

Comment: In `student_record_node`, you should declare `record` as `struct student_record record;` There is no need to use pointers for `record`. If you do use `*record` then allocate memory for it as mentioned earlier.

Comment: oh! thank you so very much.  I allocated memoery for new_student -> record and it worked.  Thank you all very much

Answer (score 1):

The memory of `record` field in `new_student` has not been allocated yet.